# Adding A New Page In CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I apologize in advance for my ignorance of CodeIgniter and the MVC system.

I'm helping a family member with their business website and up until now I've been able to complete most of the required changes just by using logic but now I've hit a dead end. I don't plan to continue supporting them as I'm obviously no CodeIgniter expert. But I'm hoping to leave the website at least functional, so that they can start using it.

I simply want to create a new "page" within the website but it seems impossible. If I can achieve this I think I can figure everything else out on my own.

For example I currently have a "page" for Cancelled Jobs. It the navigation HTML it is linked to like this:

```
http://localhost/admin/modules/cancelled_jobs
```

and has a corresponding file here:   admin/application/controllers/cancelled_jobs.php

which contains this php code:

```
class Cancelled_jobs extends CIID_Controller {


    public function __construct()

    {       

        parent::__construct();

        $this->set_table('job', 'Cancelled Job', 'Cancelled Jobs');

        $this->allow_delete = false;
        $this->allow_cancel = false;
        $this->allow_edit = false;
        $this->allow_reactivate = true;
        $this->allow_add = false;

        $this->overview
            ->add_item('Job No', 'active', 'job_id')
            ->add_item('Client', 'active|relationship', 'client.name')
            ->add_item('Name', 'active', 'name')
            ->add_item('Status', 'active|relationship', 'job_status.name')
            ->add_item('Assignee', 'active|relationship', 'team_member.name')
            ->add_item('Scheduled Date', 'active', 'scheduled_date')

            ->where("job.cancel_job = '1'")
            ->order_by('job.created_date DESC');

        $this->init();

    }


}
```

I would like to create a new "page" called Closed Jobs.

I've tried copying   admin/application/controllers/cancelled_jobs.php   and renaming it closed_jobs.php and changing the first line of code to read:

```
class Closed_jobs extends CIID_Controller {
```

I then add a link in the navigation HTML:

```
http://localhost/admin/modules/closed_jobs
```

However, when clicked, this only results in a "404 Page Not Found" error.

Can anyone point out what I'm missing in the process of creating a new page?

Comment: Turns out this is a non-standard implementation of CodeIgniter...I think. There is no modules file in the Controller directory but there is a module file which then references a MySQL table called modules. All I had to do to get it to work was to add a new record in this table for the new 'Closed Jobs' page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, CodeIgniter URLstructure is:

```
sitename.com/controller_name/function_name/parameter_1/parameter_2/parameter_3/
```

You can add as many parameters as you want.

To access

`modules/closed_jobs`:

Add a new function in the controller `modules`

```
function closed_jobs() {
  $this->load->view('closed_jobs');
}
```

And create a view `closed_jobs.php`

in `application/views`

Repeat the same for `cancelled_jobs`

Comment: Thank You, this was the hint I needed to find the answer. Turns out it's a non standard implementation of CodeIgniter. Will explain more in original question.