# .Htaccess Rewrites File Prevents new Web Pages from being Viewed, 404 Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am editing a website for a client and have hit a bit of a roadblock. I can edit and publish existing pages just fine, but if I were to create a new `.php` or `.html` page and try to view it online, I get sent to the 404 error page. I can take the new page I want and rename it to overwrite an existing page and everything loads fine.

I have tried some different ways to do the rules I need, but they either try to find the page in the root (When it's actually in `/application/views/`); or it works and I have the same problem as before.

I need help making a new `.htaccess` file that allows you to go to `website.com/signup` and it takes you to `/application/views/signup.php`. Below are some examples of what I've tried so far.

Original `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 
!^(index\.php|images|css|js|uploads|db|fonts|blogger|support|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Another version that has the same issue.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Lastly, a version that allows new pages to be viewed but looks for them in the root folder. Eg. The requested URL `/signup.php` was not found on this server. I imagine if this is modified it will work, but I have no experience with `.htaccess` rules. Much appreciated to anyone that can help me and future browsers!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.htm [NC,L]
```

Comment: To clarify, you appear to be adding entirely _static_ files to an existing framework/CMS of some kind? Or are you trying to add additional pages to the "framework" (whatever framework this might be) - which would explain why changing existing pages appears to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a couple of conditions (`RewriteCond` directives) to the *original* `.htaccess` file rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|uploads|db|fonts|blogger|support|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

So, only if the request does not map to an actual file or directory will it be rewritten (to the front controller).

Comment: This helps, I can now navigate to something in the root. Eg. website.com/test.php   But any subfolders beyond that have the same issue as before. As for your comment, I don't think this is a CMS website, just a website with some ties to a database for user management and thats about it.

Comment: "I don't think this is a CMS website" - it's just that the original `.htaccess` file is a _front controller_. In other words, all requests are passed to `index.php`, which presumably knows how to route these URLs? Regarding the "subfolders" - this should also work for subfolders, providing there are no additional `.htaccess` files in these subfolders? Presumably there are no other directives in the original `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Oh, in that case... This website uses codeignighter framework. No other .htaccess files. The index.php file IS routing them, but it still doesn't make sense to me that I can't add new pages either way. Any tips? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: If you are using CodeIgniter then you should probably be [adding new pages to CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141225/adding-a-new-page-in-codeigniter), rather than adding static pages and working _outside_ the framework? `index.php` needs to know _how_ these URLs are routed, which would seem to be the missing step here.